# Using forward_list::push_front() with a struct object

Tags: c++, stl, singly-linked-list

I wanted to start using the STL version of singly-linked lists and I came across a problem. If I want my list to be made up of struct-type objects and not just simple, native types like int, char, etc., I have a dilemma on how I can then use the push_front() function, as it only takes one argument. So how can I insert new objects with a code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

int main()
{
    forward_list<Node> myList;
    myList.push_front(???);
}
```

??? I appreciate any help given!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myList.push_front({3.14, 2.71});`, `myList.push_front(Node{3.14, 2.71});` and

```
Node n;
n.x = 3.14;
n.y = 2.71;
myList.push_front(n);
```

should all work. [Example](http://ideone.com/dPsDnR).

Comment: thank you so much!!! one more thing: if instead of a struct, I had a class, how would I still do this?

Comment: @Otringal in C++ `struct` == `class`, sans default access modifiers.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: well actually in C++ structs do have access modifiers. What I think you wanted to say is that struct == class except that struct members are public by default, while class members are private by default. Anyway, the reason why I've asked was that I wasn't sure if the order of {a, b, c, etc.} would still be mapped correctly like in the case of a struct.

Comment: @Otringal I said "sans default access modifiers" meaning they differ. If your class is an aggregate, you can use aggregate initialization just fine. If your class (or struct) is not an aggregate, define some constructors and either let uniform initialization do its work, or use `emplace_front`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: I always thought "sans" means "without".. Here's a [link](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sans)

Comment: @Otringal yes, it is used in this sense. I should have wrote _struct equals class without taking into account default access modifiers_.